Harmonizing a simple melody
I am trying to learn harmonizing simple melodies by triads (I-IV-V progression). One of the very first exercises (exercise #2 actually) in the text that I use puzzles me:

I have to specify that I am at the very elementary level - one of the three chords (I, IV or V) is associated with every note of the melody and spelled in four voices - so I am puzzled about what to do with the Diez/sharp: either it requires a new chord or does not have a chord of its own...
I admit that my formal musical education ended very early (and long ago): I can read the score and know the names of intervals and tonalities, but there may be some basic truth about the minor scale that I am ignorant of.
Thank you for your advice.

What's a Diez? You mean the F#?

Yes, I mean "sharp", sorry.

It's odd that this is such an early exercise, partly because it's in minor; it's common to spend a bit of time in major first. Maybe consider a different book? The lessons at https://www.musictheory.net/lessons might need other sources to help explain along with them, but they cover all the basics.

Also: unless it's a special rule for an exercise, it's rare for there to be a new chord for every note of a melody. If I were told to harmonize this, with no other instructions, I'd probably use one chord per measure.

@AndyBonner I'm thinking the author of the exercise might ask for a chord per tone and not per measure because a chord per measure requires deciding which tones are important enough to get a corresponding chord, and which should do without. I wouldn't be too surprised if they were saving such complex dilemmas for later. (But, I mean, I don't know; the only books I learned anything about music from were songbooks. Observation without explanation.)

The key signature indicates one of two keys - B♭ or G minor. The G minor key often uses F♯ as its leading note, to arrive back at the tonic, as it does here. That F♯ can be found in the scales of G harmonic minor, and also G melodic minor. So you're on the right track. Yes, this snippet is in key G minor, clues are the start and end notes of - G.
Reference also Beethoven's Fur Elise. The first few notes are E and D♯. The key is A minor. That D♯ isn't a leading note at all, but a chromatic embellishment, adding colour to it all. It's not even part of the A minor scale systems!

I was kinda hoping for the asker to figure it out all by himself. (He seems to only lack confidence, not erudition needed for the task.)

@Divizna - merely answering the question with some explanation to help them on their way...

@Divizna Stack Exchange fundamentally is about answering questions (that meet whichever site's standards), not about tutoring the OP. Questions are read many times more than they are written; what matters is whether the question will be helpful to someone else (which is also a good reason to have high editorial standards, look for duplicates etc.).

@Divizna in retrospective I realize that the question was elementary, and I do often adopt the same strategy as you, if something of this level is asked in my domain of knowledge. I also admit that I chose not the best text for attacking harmonization after a long break from musical theory - the other books that I looked up since then do the basic review of major&minor, mentioning this point (or perhaps I now pay more attention it it.) Anyway, the discussion in this thread has been very interesting and inspiring! I learned a lot.

The key is G Minor.  Therefore:

The I chord (because it is minor it's usually written as the lower case i) is G minor
The IV chord (which should be written as iv chord) is C minor
The V chord is D major

You're asking what to do with the chord for the 2nd beat of measure 1 where there is an F# in the melody.  F is the 7th degree of the G Minor key.  Harmonic minor is the most common minor scale, so raising the F to F# is very common, especially because the next note is the tonic.  No, the type of the minor key is not indicated in the key signature, you have to guess it from the score.  You would then need to choose a chord that has this note, and the D major chord fits the bill.
But do you have to change chord for the F#?  You basically have two options:

Treat the F# as a melodic passing tone, so the chord (G minor) can remain the same throughout the 1st measure.
Change the chord every beat, so you would use G minor (i) for the first and 3rd beats and D major (V) for the second beat.

If this is a textbook exercise, the "correct" choice depends on the textbook's "rules" of what counts as "correct" for the exercise's sake.
In the real world scenario though, I would use option #1.  It really comes down to the style of music you want to create, for pop music you can get away with one chord per measure.  But in older style SATB hymn harmonization you may want to change chord for every note in measures 2-4, although I have seen hymn harmonization that doesn't do that.  Either way, using a 2nd inversion i chord for the 2nd beat of the 3rd measure, making the phrase ends with a conventional iv - i 6/4 - V - i cadence, is a very common "hymn style" harmonization, especially for the older style.

OP has indicated 4 voices, i.e. 4-part harmony. The most common examples are hymn tunes. The expectation is usually a new chord for each note, as all parts need a note for every syllable. There are also the usual rules about consecutive 5ths and octaves etc.

@Peter I have seen hymn tunes being harmonized into SATB using either approach; newer ones tend to use the first option, even though there is a dissonance in the 2nd beat.

I agree with Andy Bonner's comment. It's unusual that a harmony textbook would start into minor key harmony so early!
Something that can help with general harmony guidelines is harmonization of the major and minor scales with the scale placed in either the soprano or the bass. Here is an example from Allen Forte's Tonal Harmony in Concept and Practice.

You can find other harmonizations in other textbooks, but they will be similar to those examples from Forte.
The harmonization of a bass scale is also know as the rule of the octave from figured bass tradition.
While these scale harmonizations will not cover all situations they do provide good general rules. They are especially helpful for associating certain scale degree, and scale degree movements, to particular chords. The minor scale harmonization are especially practical, because they show the very typical treatment of the "raised" or "lowered" sixth and seventh scale degree in regard to the melodic direction of those scale degrees.
In your case the question was about how to harmonize the seventh scale degree leading tone. For the scale harmonizations you can see the leading tone rising to the first scale degree (the tonic degree) is harmonized as some kind of dominant chord (viio or V) to a tonic chord (I or i.)

I have to specify that I am at the very elementary level - one of the three chords (I, IV or V)

Notice how the scale harmonizations focus on those basic chords: I, IV, V.
As you progress to more complex harmony keep in mind that V and IV can be abstracted to include lists of associated chords with the same harmonic function, ex. V, V7, viio, viio7 for an abstract dominant chord, and IV, ii, ii7, iio, iio7 for an abstract subdominant chord. For example, in a place where a IV chord can be used you often could alternately use a ii, ii7, etc.

After a brief search, it seems that I am dealing with a harmonic minor scale, which has a raised seventh degree... this however is not indicated at the clef. So I simply need to use the triad appropriate to this scale - with the raised F.

So far (haven't looked at it very long either) I think you're on the right track.

I am assuming that for this problem you are dealing with subdominant (minor) tonic and dominant (major, using f#)
it must start on tonic (if it is a strong beat, which it is). F# means dominant and it must resolve to tonic (D-S is usually forbidden). A means dominant and goes to tonic again. then the usual subdominant to cadential six-four to dominant and then to tonic. (my harmony book also does minor and major at the same time. It is not that much harder.)
